# автоскрытие расширений .htacces

Tags: .htaccess, apache

столкнулся с задачей убрать расширение файлов при запросе к сайту.
Собственно с помощью .htacces сделал это,но в случае если пользователь вписывает самостоятельно расширение - оно остается. Смотрел у ВК это пофикшено и оно опять убирается. Подскажите как это сделать?

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На самом дело оказалось куда проще и секрет стоял в react-е жс

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /subdirectory
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```